# CSS Hover Expand

Tags: html, css, text, hover

I need to expand a section of my advert when it is hovered on

please see here: https://jsfiddle.net/u7kpc9jL/2/

I would like the bottom to align to the bottom of the advert and I also need to show different text when expanded.

Any ideas?

CSS

```
body {
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    border:solid 2px;
}

.legal:hover {
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    top:80px;

}

.legal-text {
    padding-top:2px;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}

.legal {
    height:17px;
    width:85px;
    background-color:#006fba;
    left:0px;
    top:100px;
    z-index:110;
    margin-top:233px;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, your `z-index` property and your `top`/`left` position properties aren't applied unless you also apply a non-default `position` property to those selectors as well (like `position: relative;`)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of changes to make to get this working. I'll just put comment markers by them. Note that there are some items removed from your demo relating to position and size.

```
body {
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    border:solid 2px;
    position: relative; /* */
}
.legal {
    height:17px;
    width:85px;
    background-color:#006fba;
    left:0px;
    position: absolute; /* */
    bottom: 0; /* */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.legal:hover {
    height: 80px; /* */
    width: 150px; /* */
}
.legal-text, .alternate-text { /* */
    padding-top: 2px;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.alternate-text {
    display: none; /* */
}
.legal:hover .alternate-text {
    display: block; /* */
}
.legal:hover .legal-text {
    display: none; /* */
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u7kpc9jL/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your code slightly:

```
body {
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    border:solid 2px;
}

.legal:hover {
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    top:80px;

}

.legal-text {
    padding-top:2px;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}

.legal {
    height:17px;
    width:85px;
    background-color:#006fba;
    left:0px;
    top:100px;
    z-index:110;
    margin-top:233px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the box on hover to dynamically cover the width and change the text as well. Please check the
[**UPDATED JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u7kpc9jL/9/)

```css
body {
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    border:solid 2px;
}
.parent {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.legal {
    background-color:#006fba;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: auto;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.legal:hover {
    width:100%;
    /* To make sure the width is aligned with the parent div */
    cursor:default;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.legal-text, .legal span {
    padding:2px 10px;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
.legal span {
    display:none;
    padding:11px 10px;
    /* Expanded text is hidden */
}
.legal:hover p {
    display:none;
    /* the text is hidden */
}
.legal:hover span {
    display:block;
    /* Expanded text is shown */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="legal">
            <p class="legal-text">Boring Legals here</p> <span>"Here's my expanded text"</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute;` in combination with `bottom:0;` to have the text stick at the bottom. And with the `:after` pseudoclass in combination with `:hover`, you can change the text via css:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    border:solid 2px;
}

.legal:hover {
    height:40px;
    width:250px;    
}

.legal-text {

    padding-top:2px;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}

.legal-text:after {
    content: 'Boring Legals here';
}

.legal:hover .legal-text:after {
    content: 'Hover text';
}

.legal {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height:17px;
    width:85px;
    background-color:#006fba;
    left:0px;
    z-index:110;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u7kpc9jL/5/